# How to do continuous delivery with Jenkins?

Tags: delphi, jenkins, svn, cobol, visual-sourcesafe

I am working for a company now for a couple of weeks. The build process is done mostly manually and takes several hours spread over several days. The languages in use are C#, COBOL, Delphi, Visual Basic 6, and of course the database with T-SQL. For the version control, we use Apache Subversion (SVN), except for COBOL code and the documentation, which is kept in Microsoft Visual SourceSafe (VSS). I have the idea to improve the process using a continuous delivery tool. Do you think that [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_(software)) would do the job?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: The answer to the question that you asked is yes.

Comment: As what the answer would be for nearly every Turing complete system. The question is how much trouble it will be

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins is undoubtedly a tool that can help with CI/CD.

Whether it is the right tool for your particular needs you should be able to determine by doing your own research into the capabilities of Jenkins and the tooling that it supports.  You may find that you struggle with finding adequate support for the older technologies that you mention and you will likely find that you need to uplift some of that legacy to make it usefully available to any viable, modern CI/CD tool.

e.g. get your code out of SourceSafe.  You should do that anyway because .. SourceSafe.  :)

Don't get bogged down in how to migrate your history.  Just shutter SourceSafe (make it read-only) to retain as a reference to your history and move tip/head into a new repo.  (SVN if you have to, though I'd highly recommend Git).

More generally, I would be surprised if you could not find some immediate quick-win improvements that can be made, without needing to invest time/effort/money into a "Silver Bullet" tool, just by putting some scripting in place to automate current manual processes.

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins is definitely the right tool. We use Jenkins as a CI tool for building our Delphi (+Dunit+Innosetup), C# and Cordova/PhoneGap applications (all code in SVN).

I have no idea of the dependencies between the code in SVN of VSS, but if it depends on each other, I would advise to put all the code in a SVN or GIT repository.

There are some simple examples to integrate Delphi in Jenkins, see the following links:

https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/continuous-integration-with-svn-jenkins-and-dunit-delphi-with-craig-chapman

http://www.ictexpertise.com/blog/2016/02/10/continuous-integration-of-delphi-project-with-jenkins/

http://chapmanworld.com/2015/01/18/use-radstudio-with-jenkins-no-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for your information. My company has still not decided to use Jenkins, but it is for me a good choice. I heard from a project manager recently that his software architect spend five weeks still Jenkins worked satisfactorily for a large Java project. I think it will take at least two month for me, as I have hardly any administrative experience in my carrier.